# git: 'credential-osxkeychainit' is not a git command. See 'git --help'

Tags: git

When I try to push committed changes back to the repo from command line on Mac OS X

`git push`

I get the following message:

`git: 'credential-osxkeychainit' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

This is irrespective of if everything is up to date or not.

Any ideas what can be messed up?

Comment: Do you have an alias set up for `git push`? What does `git config alias.push` display? Similarly, have you configured `credential.helper`?

Comment: I have not setup any alias for `git push`. Checking with `config` returns empty. `git credential.helper` returns `osxkeychain`.

Comment: `osxkeychainit` seems like the strange part. Does that appear somewhere in your `~/.gitconfig` (or `.git/config`)?

Comment: Yup. That was it. I think at some point helper got set to `osxkeychainit` accidentally. Thanks @Kristján !

Answer (score 1):

[This post](http://blog.sdbarker.com/git-credential-caching-on-windows/) (from 2011...) explain why it does not work under windows.

> This `git-credential-cache` doesn’t work for Windows systems as `git-credential-cache` communicates through a Unix socket.

Try this is might solve your problem:

```
git config --global credential.helper wincred
```

Comment: My problem happens on OS X.